# Displays data as user_id

Tags: php, laravel

I am logged in with the user I have and all I want is my account can only see the data I just sent. Here I find a problem that is able to see the data of others.

First this is Model Data

```
public function user()
{
// Each data is owned by only one user
return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

And then Model User

```
public function data()
{
// Each user will have a lot of data
return $this->hasMany('App\Data');
}
```

The last this is controller

```
public function index()
{
  $show_data = Auth::user()->data();
  $show_data = Data::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)
                 ->paginate(10);
  $amount_of_data = Data::count();
  return view('data.index', compact('show_data', 'amount_of_data'));
}
```

Comment: Also, why are you assigning $show_data and then immediately reassigning it?

Comment: `Data::count()`: you count the whole rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Model For Data

```
public function data()
{
  // Each user will have a lot of data
  return $this->hasMany('App\Data','user_id');
}
```

Final Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $show_data = Auth::user()->data()->paginate(10);
    $amount_of_data = count($show_data['data']);
    return view('data.index', compact('show_data', 'amount_of_data'));
}
```

Comment: there's wrong here. $amount_of_data will count the $show_data paginate instead of real user data amount

Answer (score 0):

Edit index method to this and try:

```
public function index()
{
    $show_data = auth()->user()->data()->paginate(10);
    $show_data_count = count(auth()->user()->data);

    return view('data.index', compact('show_data', 'show_data_count'));
}
```